# HASKELL - Change Type

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I need to create a function `f:: Log->[String]`  that does that  `(((o, i ,d),s) = [(o, i ,d)]`

```
type Log = (Plate, [String])
```

`type Plate = (Pin, Pin, Pin)`
    `type Pin = (Char, Int)`

Comment: You're not being clear. Are you looking for a function with type `Log -> [String]`?

Comment: n.b. `Plate` is a type. `Plate (o,i,d)` is *not* a type.

Comment: yes.. function with type `Log->[String]`

Comment: In no time I used `Plate (o,i,d)`

Comment: You've completely changed your question, deleting the original! Please 1) provide enough information in your original question to make your intentions clear and/or 2) post very different questions as new questions instead of editing. I know you were encouraged to put new code in your question last time, but you weren't encouraged to put new _questions_! (Maybe if you need interactive, iterative assistance with your code, you coult use chat, or #haskell on freenode irc and hpaste.) You're welcome to keep asking here, though! In your next question, try to explain what you're aiming at in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
g :: Log -> [String]
g (plate, _) = [show plate]
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're on [a page like this](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html), click "Source" on the fir right side, next to the function that you're interested in.

If you need to look up a function, [Hayoo!](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html) and [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) will link you to documentation pages like the one above.

An important thing to note, though is that `show` doesn't have one definition. `show` is a function defined for all data types in the `Show` (with a capital "S") typeclass. So for example, here is the full source for [the Show typeclass](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/GHC-Show.html#show). Show is defined within the typeclass as just `show :: a -> String`. But if you search for "instance Show Bool" or "instance Show Int", you'll find specific definitions.

---

For the second part of your question, the easiest way to get a `show` function for a new type is to simply write `deriving (Show)` below it. For example,

```
data Foo = Foo Int Int
   deriving (Show)
```

Now I can use `show` on data with type `Foo`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) to find this sort of information.

Example: http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=show

Once you've found the function you'd like in the list, click and there you'll find a `Source` link on the right hand side of the page.

NB this is an answer to the original question:

> Where can I see the codes of the predefined functions in haskell ?? Mainly the function SHOW?

Answer (score 1):

It's true that you can use Hoogle to search for functions defined in the Prelude (and other modules), but the source code itself is located at Hackage.

[Hackage](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/hackage.html) is a database of Haskell packages. You can download new packages from it, and also view the Haddock documentation for every package in the database.

[This is the Haddock page for the standard Prelude](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html). It documents the type classes, data types, types, and top-level functions exported by the Prelude module. To the right of each definition header is a link that says "Source". You can click this to be taken to an online copy of the source code for the module you're viewing.

---

On preview, you're now asking a different question entirely, and on preview again in fact the original question has been edited out of this post.

Your new question is unclear, but this solution will work to produce the output in your example.

```
> [fst ((('O',0),('I',0),('D',1)),"O->D")]
[(('O',0),('I',0),('D',1))]
```

I think you're using list notation instead of double quotes to identify `String`s, by the way, so I fixed that around `0->D` above. So you might also try this instead.

```
> show (fst ((('O',0),('I',0),('D',1)),"O->D"))
"(('O',0),('I',0),('D',1))"
```

This works because you have only defined type synonyms (by using `type` in your declarations instead of `data`) on data structures which already have `Show` instances.

Comment: `[(o, i, d)]` does not have the type `[String]`. Maybe you what you want is `[show (fst ((('O',0),('I',0),('D',1)),"0->D"))]` which produces `["(('O',0),('I',0),('D',1))"]` which has the type `[String]`?